# Android / iPhone href link not firing - focus rectangle appearing instead

Tags: android, iphone, html, responsive-design

I am having a problem on android and iPhone versions of HTML5 site using responsive layout.

links are not firing unless I hold down on them for 1 second. 
Otherwise they act as if a hover event was taking place.

Example code:

```
<div class="homepageCarDiv">

        <div class="note">

            <div class="imgDiv">
                **<a href="ficha-vehiculo.php?v=19"><img src="_imgup/19/thumbnail/Imagen_2.jpg" alt=""></a>**
            </div>

             <h3>MITSUBISHI ASX<br>ASX 200 DI-D CHALLENGE 4WD (2010)</h3>

             <h4>16.500€</h4>


            <div class="verDet">
            <p>**<a href="ficha-vehiculo.php?v=19" class="homeBut">Ver Detalle</a>**</p>
            </div>

        <div class="cornerImage">
        <img src="images/fold.png" alt="">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Code can be seen at http://20coches.com/index.php.

It works correctly on iPad and desktop.
I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was related to responsive divs and focus rectangles being pushed out of the viewport.

Other sources on the internet suggest that javascript calculations of the dynamic element width causes a silent mouse fail on hover, which results in the link not firing.

I just got tired of beating my head against the VDU, and managed to work around the issue - by clearing every div from its neighbour.